# how to limit edit events on dynamic form changes

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a form building app, and I use an event of type edit, each time updating the form in the DB.
But the problem is that my form builder auto saves each change which causes a lot of edit events to occur.
Is there a way to limit the edit events creation, like only consider the last change in the form as an edit event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want some [underscore power](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

```
var saveFunction = function(dataToSave) { ... },
    debouncedSaved = _.debounce(saveFunction, 700);
```

In this example, `debouncedSaved` will only be eventually called if left idle for 700 milliseconds.
It should be easily adapted to your code, you can use debounced functions as event handlers since they're still classic functions.

Comment: thanks and will the function call occur with the new params or the old params

Comment: New params of course! Test it on the underscore's doc: `var log = _.debounce(function(t) { console.log(t) }, 500); log(1); log(2); log(3);`